# How to create dynamic app shortcut using ShortcutManager API for android 7.1 app?

Tags: android, android-7.1-nougat, android-appshortcut

In Android 7.1, developer can able to create [AppShortCut](https://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html#shortcuts).

We can create shortcut in two way:

1. Static shortcuts using resources(XML) file.
2. Dynamic shortcuts using `ShortcutManager` API.

So How to create a shortcut using `ShortcutManager` dynamically?

Comment: AppShortcuts simple project: https://developer.android.com/samples/AppShortcuts/index.html

Comment: Now the sample project is here https://github.com/android/user-interface-samples/tree/master/AppShortcuts/#readme

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using `ShortcutManager`, we can create app dynamic app shortcut in following way:

```
ShortcutManager shortcutManager;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        shortcutManager = getSystemService(ShortcutManager.class);
        ShortcutInfo shortcut;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1) {
            shortcut = new ShortcutInfo.Builder(this, "second_shortcut")
                    .setShortLabel(getString(R.string.str_shortcut_two))
                    .setLongLabel(getString(R.string.str_shortcut_two_desc))
                    .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(this, R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                    .setIntent(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse("https://www.google.co.in")))
                    .build();
            shortcutManager.setDynamicShortcuts(Arrays.asList(shortcut));
        }


    }
```

String resources:

```
<string name="str_shortcut_two">Shortcut 2</string>
<string name="str_shortcut_two_desc">Shortcut using code</string>
```

Developer can also perform different tasks app shortcut using `ShortcutManager`:

- **Publish**: Use [setDynamicShortcuts(List)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ShortcutManager.html#setDynamicShortcuts(java.util.List<android.content.pm.ShortcutInfo>)) to redefine the entire list of dynamic shortcuts, or use [addDynamicShortcuts(List)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ShortcutManager.html#addDynamicShortcuts(java.util.List<android.content.pm.ShortcutInfo>)) to augment an existing list of dynamic shortcuts.
- **Update**: Use the [updateShortcuts(List)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ShortcutManager.html#updateShortcuts(java.util.List<android.content.pm.ShortcutInfo>)) method.
- **Remove**: Remove a set of dynamic shortcuts using [removeDynamicShortcuts(List)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ShortcutManager.html#removeDynamicShortcuts(java.util.List<java.lang.String>)), or remove all dynamic shortcuts using [removeAllDynamicShortcuts()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ShortcutManager.html#removeAllDynamicShortcuts()).

[image: App Shortcut]

Check Github example for [App Shortcut](https://github.com/pranaypatel512/AppShortCut)

Check https://developer.android.com/preview/shortcuts.html and [ShortcutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ShortcutManager.html)  to get more info.

Comment: M? Isn't it available after API 25?

Answer (score 6):

We can use ShortcutManager for a intent action like this

```
ShortcutManager shortcutManager = getSystemService(ShortcutManager.class);

ShortcutInfo webShortcut = new ShortcutInfo.Builder(this, "shortcut_web")
        .setShortLabel("catinean.com")
        .setLongLabel("Open catinean.com web site")
        .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(this, R.drawable.ic_dynamic_shortcut))
        .setIntent(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://catinean.com")))
        .build();

shortcutManager.setDynamicShortcuts(Collections.singletonList(webShortcut));
```

we can use ShortcutManager to open an activity like this

```
    ShortcutInfo dynamicShortcut = new ShortcutInfo.Builder(this, "shortcut_dynamic")
        .setShortLabel("Dynamic")
        .setLongLabel("Open dynamic shortcut")
        .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(this, R.drawable.ic_dynamic_shortcut_2))
        .setIntents(
                new Intent[]{
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, Uri.EMPTY, this, MainActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK),
                })
        .build();
shortcutManager.setDynamicShortcuts(Arrays.asList(dynamicShortcut, dynamicShortcut));
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Perfect Solution for all devices (Pre/Post Oreo device).

```
createShortcut(CurrentActivity.this, ActivityToOpen.class, "app name", R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
```

Put this in your Util.

```
 public static void createShortcut(@NonNull Activity activity, Class activityToOpen, String title, @DrawableRes int icon) {
        Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(activity, activityToOpen);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) { // code for adding shortcut on pre oreo device 
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, title);
            intent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
            Parcelable parcelable = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(activity, icon);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, parcelable);
            activity.sendBroadcast(intent);
            System.out.println("added_to_homescreen");
        } else { 
            ShortcutManager shortcutManager = activity.getSystemService(ShortcutManager.class);
            assert shortcutManager != null;
            if (shortcutManager.isRequestPinShortcutSupported()) {
                ShortcutInfo pinShortcutInfo =
                        new ShortcutInfo.Builder(activity, "browser-shortcut-")
                                .setIntent(shortcutIntent)
                                .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(activity, icon))
                                .setShortLabel(title)
                                .build();

                shortcutManager.requestPinShortcut(pinShortcutInfo, null);
                System.out.println("added_to_homescreen");
            } else {
                System.out.println("failed_to_add");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It will complain shortcutIntent doesn't have action

Comment: This answer is better if you want to create a shortcut of your activity, just one thing is that you will have to set shortcut intent according to your needs, in my case it was this:
`new Intent(applicationContext,Activity.class)`. Hope it helps someone who is looking for shortcut of an Activity

Answer (score 0):

We should set the shortcut intent to Target Activity rather than mentioning implicit intents.

Eg:

```
ShortcutManager shortcutManager = null;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1) {
        shortcutManager =  getSystemService(ShortcutManager.class);
        Intent intent= new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("weburl"));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        ShortcutInfo shortcut = new ShortcutInfo.Builder(this, "shortcutId")
                .setShortLabel("dummy")
                .setLongLabel("dummy").setRank(0)
                .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(this, R.drawable.ic_launcher_background))
                .setIntent(intent).build();

         shortcutManager.setDynamicShortcuts(Arrays.asList(shortcut));
}
```

And Activity in my Manifest.xml is :

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Am landing to my MainActivity on clicking the dynamic shortCut which handles Action_VIEW .

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Shortcuts:
ShortcutManager is used to manage all the dynamic Shortcuts. ShortcutInfo represents single shortcut, which will then be added to ShortcutManager via ShortcutInfo.Builder.

```
   //......................................* Java Dynamic Shortcuts
ShortcutManager shortcutManager = getSystemService(ShortcutManager.class);

Intent thirdIntent = new Intent(this,ThirdActivity.class);
thirdIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

ShortcutInfo thirdScreenShortcut = new ShortcutInfo.Builder(this, "shortcut_third")
 .setShortLabel("Third Activity")
 .setLongLabel("This is long description for Third Activity")
 .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(this, R.drawable.your_image))
 .setIntent(thirdIntent)
 .build();
 shortcutManager.setDynamicShortcuts(Collections.singletonList(thirdScreenShortcut));








  //......................................*  KOTLIN Dynamic Shortcuts
 val shortcutManager = getSystemService(ShortcutManager::class.java)


            val thirdIntent = Intent(this, ActivityThree::class.java)
            thirdIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW

            val dynamicShortcut = ShortcutInfo.Builder(this, "shortcut_third")
                .setShortLabel("Third Activity")
                .setLongLabel("This is long description for Third Activity")
                .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(this, R.drawable.your_image))
                .setIntents(
                    arrayOf(
                        Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_MAIN,
                            Uri.EMPTY,
                            this,
                            MainActivity::class.java
                        ).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK),
                        thirdIntent
                    )
                )
                .build()

  shortcutManager!!.dynamicShortcuts = listOf(dynamicShortcut)
```

Key Notes :
https://androidkeynotes.blogspot.com/2020/02/app-shortcuts.html