# How to implement event listeners on app shortcut icon?

Tags: android, icons

I would like to create an app that deals with background pictures of the a user device. But when a user clicks the shortcut icon, the background should change without opening the app and the icon should be somehow animated.

Let's consider this application in Itel:

Before I click on the app shortcut icon
[image]

And after click, the app doesn't open but the background changes and the icon animates(see the picture):

[image]

How can someone achieve this?

Comment: Is this app built-in into the system? Does it behave the same if it's used with a custom app launcher? This might be just a hard-coded behavior in the launcher app.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts/managing-shortcuts may be this link helps you

Comment: @Pawel I installed another launcher and it behaves the same way

Comment: what API level are you targeting?

Comment: In case you can't animate/change the app icon itself, instead you may be able to open an activity that is completely transparent and play the animation there so it looks like the icon were animated.

Comment: @BLuFeNiX The target SDK is 26

Comment: You could try to use [Adaptive icons](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. AFAIK we cannot change app icon at runtime. My guess, The icon in the example above may be a widget
2. About changing background wallpaper (or performing a particular task): I think we can create a launcher activity **(a transparent one/without `setContentView()`)** which will `finish()` itself after **triggering a background service that changes the wallpaper (or perform any other task)**. According to my opinion, this can be a solution for the scenario above though I haven't tried it personally

Best regards, Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr** You can't change it because the icon of your app is registered in the Android Manifest that ships with it.

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro):

> **Icons and labels**
>
> A number of manifest elements have an icon and label attributes for
>   displaying a small icon and a text label, respectively, to users for
>   the corresponding app component.

That means that your app will always have the same icon since the manifest cannot be changed in runtime. So my guess is that the app you reference is a system app, with system privileges.

The only icons that you can change are the shortcuts your app creates using this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
```

To create a shortcut, please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40446734/1574250

---

To change the background when clicking in your app icon, here is an example (in this example I'm only changing the background color when the app opens):

**Class:**

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set you app icon
        setColorWallpaper();

        // Finish the activity
        finish();
    }

    /**
     * Sets the color wallpaper to the color value in the Clipboard, or to a random color.
     */
    private void setColorWallpaper() {

        // Try to get the color parameter from the clipboard
        Integer colorParam = null;
        try {
            colorParam = ColorClipboardParameter.getColor(getApplication());
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
            // An unexpected exception while trying to get the color code from the clipboard
            // can crash the app at startup. Ignore any exceptions, we will generate a random
            // color anyway.
        }

        // If there is no valid color value in the clipboard, generate a random color
        final int color = (colorParam != null) ? colorParam : GoodRandomColor.nextColor();

        try {
            // Set the color wallpaper
            ColorWallpaper.setColorWallpaper(this, color);

            // Success: copy the color code to the clipboard
            Utils.copyText(this, Utils.colorToHex(color));

            // Go to the home screen
            Utils.goHome(this);

        } catch (IOException e) {

            // Write the stack trace to System.err and copy the reason of the failure to clipboard
            e.printStackTrace();
            Utils.copyText(this, e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

**Manifest:**

```
<application
    android:fullBackupContent="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

    <activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

</application>
```

Check this project for more info: https://github.com/appgramming/LoneColor-Android